# Remember visitor PHP

Tags: javascript, php, evercookie

I develop website and want to remember visitor already vote for my site like this [website](http://mfmradio.fr/top20).

After i research, [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) is a method to remember visitor.

In the website they protect only once they can vote on a song, even they clear standard cookie, use others browser...

Question: Can it's have other methods to remember beside of evercookie?

Comment: evercookie, more like lawsuitcookie. bad, bad, bad practices tend to spread fast.

Comment: *Its goal is to identify a client even after they've removed standard
cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared Objects or LSOs), and others.* Selling fake Viagra or something?

Comment: There is no way to prevent people from voting more than once. If somebody wants to do it he can circumvent everything you try to prevent it.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, the website is allow only once for a song even you delete standard cookie or use difference browser to vote

Comment: @ChandaraSam And I just voted multiple times for the same entry using tor.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method, store a session variable.
On top of page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['hasVoted'] = "No";
?>
```

then in youre code:

```
<?php
   if( $_SESSION['hasVoted'] == "No")
     {
        $_SESSION['hasVoted'] = "Yes"; 

        //Here goes youre code for submitting the vote.
     }
?>
```

The downside: when session has been lost, the user can vote again.
Another way is by using a database to store the users IP adress.
using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` you can get the viewers ip adress and store that in your DataBase.
Hope this helps.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] show the same IP on the same network even on difference computer

Comment: Yes, there is a downside to them, but if you want to avoid using cookies then those are a workaround.

Comment: You could also force people to create a account first

Comment: make visitor friendly, and it just a vote no need them to register

Comment: Then you should use a cookie, but still, if they clear all browser data and cookies. They can vote again. Without a login its hard to register since we cannot get Mac Adresses from the computer.  I advise you to use the Session. If the answer above is what you are looking for, Please mark as answer